# Create DRF serializers class dynamically

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a few DRF serializer classes of the same model. I want to move the class creation code to a function to avoid code repetition.

So basically I have to return a class from a function, but I am unable **to access the function parameters inside the class**.

```
def get_course_serializer(fields, read_only_fields=None):
    class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        if "id" in fields:
            id = serializers.CharField(default="", read_only=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Course
            fields = fields
            if read_only_fields:
                read_only_fields = read_only_fields

return CourseSerializer
```

Here the **fields** aren't accessible inside the **CourseSerializer** class definition. I tried using global keyword, but it didn't work.

I am planning on using this function as below

```
CourseListSerializer = get_course_serializer(
["id", "title", "slug", "description"])
```

Comment: Does `nonlocal` work instead of `global`? If not you may have to use the 3 argument form of `type` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Comment: I'd recommend you read up on [Python namespaces and scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), you won't be able to access `fields` in your class definition. But you can use `types` (see doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html)) to dynamically create your class definition.

Comment: nonlocal also doesn't work. for using `type`, I'll have to provide method definitions and attributes, so basically I'll have to provide all the fields I need to the `type`. So there'll be again a lot of code repetions.

Comment: But you would need to do that in your approach too or am I missing something? You always need to define your attributes and class methods? I've posted an answer using the `type` approach. You also could use `types` but I don't see any benefit using it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `type` to dynamically create your class, something like this should work (untested):

```
def get_course_serializer(fields, read_only_fields=None):
    mapping = {}
    if "id" in fields:
        mapping["id"] = serializers.CharField(default="", read_only=True)
    ...
    CourseSerializer = type("CourseSerializer", (serializers.ModelSerializer, ), mapping)
    return CourseSerializer
```

Comment: Think you would also need to create the Meta class dynamically too and pass it to mapping

Comment: Yes, including the tested code in the edits. Thanks a lot, yvesonline !! This way works, but is it the best way to do it, or are there better ways to create classes dynamically?